I have Laravel project with node_modules folder. How can I deploy this project on cpanel. Please guide step by step for this
I have Laravel project with node_modules folder. How can I deploy this project on cpanel. Please guide me.
Current Laravel folder structure:
app
resources
bootstrap
....
....
node_modules
.env

I am beginner to Laravel. Before, I have deployed Laravel projects without node_modules. But now I have node_modules folder in project. Guide me to deploy.
Is there need make build like 'Angular' or what. Please help.

Always write the version in Laravel questions.
